# django how to update item

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I have postgres function

```
DECLARE office_lastnumber TEXT;
BEGIN
UPDATE curriculum.clearance_item SET resolve=TRUE,resolve_date=now() where cl_itemid=f_cl_itemid;

INSERT INTO curriculum.transaction_log (cl_itemid,trans_desc,trans_recorded)
    VALUES (f_cl_itemid,'Resolved Clearance Item',now());
    
RETURN f_cl_itemid;
END;
```

I have this list of items, cut some rows so it's easier to read

```
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <th>cl_itemid</th>
            <th colspan="2">Actions:</th>
        </tr>
        {%for data in data%}
        <tr>
            <td>{{data.cl_itemid}}</td>
        <td><a href="{% url 'update' data.cl_itemid %}">Update</a></td>
    </tr>
    {%endfor%}
</table>
```

And views.py

```
def update(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    resolve_item = # what to put here
    cursor.execute("select resolve_clearance_item('"+resolve_item+"')")
    return render(request, 'clearance/index.html')
else:
    return render(request, 'clearance/index.html')
```

cl_itemid

OSA2022-2023 | update

DORM2022-2023| update

How can ***def update*** knows if I click update (ex.OSA2022-2023) then it puts in resolve_item and run the function

Answer (score 0):

```
# ---------------- VIEW.PY ----------------
# Update Data In Student Table
def UpdateData(request,id):
    student_data = Student.objects.all() # Show data of Student Table
    get_student  = Student.objects.get(id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Student(request.POST,request.FILES,instance=set_student)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request,'Student Successfully Updated')
            return redirect('/home/')
    else:
        form = Student(instance=set_student)
    context= {'form':form,'student_data':student_data}
    return render(request,'home.html',context)
```